# How does splitActionBarWhenNarrow exactly work in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

The Android [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#uioptions) describe splitActionBarWhenNarrow like this:
"Add a bar at the bottom of the screen to display action items in the ActionBar, when constrained for horizontal space (such as when in portrait mode on a handset)."

But how is "constrained for horizontal space" defined? There seems to be no way to define when this split occurs.

Comment: yes. I have the same issues. I have defined more than 8 menu items. and switch between portrait and landscape mode, the action bar didn't split.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using ActionBarSherlock and the action bar is split when the screen width is below 480dp.
This behaviour is defined by the two following resource files :

res/values-w480dp/abs_bools.xml

```
<resources>
    <bool name="abs__action_bar_embed_tabs">true</bool>
    <bool name="abs__split_action_bar_is_narrow">false</bool>
</resources>
```

res/values/abs_bools.xml

```
<resources>
    <bool name="abs__action_bar_embed_tabs">false</bool>
    <bool name="abs__split_action_bar_is_narrow">true</bool>
</resources>
```

I have not checked if this is the same behaviour as in ICS code but I'm pretty sure it is.