# Android ActionBar Will Not Split On Device

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I know there have been many ActionBar questions but they don't seem to address my problem.  I am able to spit the ActionBar in my emulator, but when I run my program on my device (Nexus 7 portrait mode) the ActionBar will not split.  All the icons 'pile up' on top, even my tabs create a drop down list.  I have tried to force the issue by making the menu items names extremely long and I do have them set to: android:showAsAction="always|withText".  Just to be sure, I have taken sample code, ran it on the emulator seen it work and then put it on my device to no avail.  Here's my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I have scoured the web but cannot find a solution.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem. I read somewhere that the 'splitActionBar' only applies to phones, not to tablets but I hope that's a myth...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this SO item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094675/how-does-splitactionbarwhennarrow-exactly-work-in-android), the ActionBar is only splitted when the available width is less than 480dp. According to [this article](https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/6eWwQvFGLV8) of Google's Dianne Hackborn however, the portrait width of the Nexus 7 is 600dp. So that's the reason there's no splitting.

I agree with you, that the splitting should depend on the relation between available space and items to be shown, not on the available space alone.

Comment: Ridcully, thanks for digging that up.  I'm just surprised that's the case.

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is pretty old but I've found a way to force the actionbar to the buttom on the Nexus 7 (and possible other devices) and I thought I'd share my solution:

Place this code in your Activity:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public Resources getResources() {
    return new ResourceFix(super.getResources());
}

private class ResourceFix extends Resources {
    private int targetId = 0;

    ResourceFix(Resources resources) {
        super(resources.getAssets(), resources.getDisplayMetrics(), resources.getConfiguration());
        targetId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("split_action_bar_is_narrow", "bool", "android");
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean getBoolean(int id) throws Resources.NotFoundException {
        return targetId == id || super.getBoolean(id);
    }
}
```

This will force the internal "split_action_bar_is_narrow" value to true.
It might not be the best way to do this but it appears the be the only way I've found.

Comment: Nice hack. Hope it gets some visibility. It's a common question out there

Comment: Incredible. Good job!