# Overflow Actionbar items not displaying on bottom bar

Tags: android, layout, menu, android-actionbar

I am trying to add items to the bottom action bar on android. I have placed the following into my manifest as required by what I've read on Google dev.

```
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

and I have a layout file as follows:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings"
    android:visible="true"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/activityhomemen"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/activityhomemen"
    android:visible="true"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/activity1men"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/activity1men"
    android:visible="true"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/activity2men"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/activity2men"
    android:visible="true"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/activity3men"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/activity3men"
    android:visible="true"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/activity4men"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/activity4men"
    android:visible="true"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/activity5men"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/activity5men"
    android:visible="true"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/activity9men"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/activity5men"
    android:visible="true"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/activity6men"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/activity5men"
    android:visible="true"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/activity7men"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/activity5men"
    android:visible="true"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/activity8men"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/activity5men"
    android:visible="true"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/activity9men"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/activity5men"
    android:visible="true"/>
```

When I run the application on the emulator I can see the first 5 items of the menu. When I click on the overflow button I see the remaining items. Should they not be appearing on the bottom bar because of what I inserted into the manifest?...

Any help is much appreciated.

Below is screen of emulator. As you can see, overflow contains items and no bar showing at bottom...

[image]

Comment: Only in a narrow scenario (e.g., phone or phone-sized emulator, in portrait). You might consider posting screenshots of what you are seeing.

Comment: Are you using actioBarSherlock?

Comment: I am using an emulator to replicate the nexus 7. It definitely wouldn't fall under the category of phone or phone sized, but i really need to display this bar at the bottom as the design will feature 4 buttons at the bottom on each screen. I read on Google dev that the action bar was the way to go.

Comment: @Greensy no, I am using the standard ActionBar and my API level is 17 so up to date and above the minimum API14

Comment: Actually in two words, you should set target sdk to 14 if you want bottom, menu. Google deprecated it

Comment: ok il go give that a try now

Comment: I changed that but unfortunately no change! :(

Comment: The split action bar will not be displayed on "non-narrow" devices like the Nexus 7. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606778/android-actionbar-will-not-split-on-device

Answer (score -1):

If you want always show those items at the bottom. You can use tab widget in addition to you action bar. It will look like action bar on 4.0+.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html

Update:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentTabHost.html - here is this class, that helps to add fragment navigation

Comment: I'll try that out, the only thing is it means a lot more work as I need to add this widget over and over and over again to each layout that requires it which is all of them, I don't understand why Google make some things like displaying a bottom bar so difficult!!

Comment: You do not need to add it over and over. Just use Fragments api. and FragmentTabWidget class/ It really simple. Also i hightly recomend you to ise actionBarSherlock - it is a very good extention that helps a lot with action bars behavior.