# Enable Split Action bar for pre honey comb devices using action bar app compact library

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I want to show the split action bar for pre honey comb devices as same
as post honey comb devices. for that i have included the following
code in my manifest as per android docs.

```
<manifest ...>
<activity uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" ... >
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
               android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
</activity>
```

after adding this also i am unable to show the split action bar for
lower versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import AppCompat project. Make sure you have added this Action Bar Compact (ABC) theme like this:

[image]

You should extend your activity to  `ActionBarActivity`.

Have look at this for migrating from **[ABS to ABC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844517/difference-between-actionbarsherlock-and-actionbar-compatibility/18183801#18183801)**

Update: Try with removing this

> uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.test.ExampleActivity"
    android:label="@string/activity_location_found"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.test.ExampleActivity2" >
    <!-- To support below API Level 14 -->
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
           android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
</activity>
```

or   **To create this split effect, disable the action bar icon and title with setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false) and setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false).**

Other than this have a look it this [ActionBar is only splitted when the available width is less than 480dp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606778/android-actionbar-will-not-split-on-device?rq=1) try to to test the code in small devices!

Comment: I have mentioned already.. my application tag in manifest is as follows..  <application
        android:name="com.tictic.recipient.ApplicationContext"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ptalk"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >\

Comment: @Sravani have you extended your activity to ActionBarActivity ?? check the update

Comment: Yes i have extended actionbaractivity. my class declaration is like this.. public class MessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AppObserver,android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {      }.. if you have any example which is working fine in lower version devices please give me. @LOG_TAG

Comment: @Sravani http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/  use this sample!

Comment: To create this effect, disable the action bar icon and title with setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false) and setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false).

Comment: I got it finally only thing is we need to change in menu fine... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> For enable the Split action bar for lower versions we need to Add the
>   theme and meta-data tag in our manifest . and also we need to change
>   the menu file as follows..

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
to
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
```

> and also showsAsAction tag should change from

```
android:showAsAction="always"
to
yourapp:showAsAction="always"
```